# Input field in highcharts graphic

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

I have a Highcharts graphic http://jsfiddle.net/jerryvermanen/XRjyc/, but I would like to add an input field. The input field asks for a year. After input:

- The graphic should add one year to the input year (so 1992 becomes 1993).
- The graphic should display a vertical plot line on the input year + 1 (so a line on 1993).
- It should also add a line on five years after that (1998), and five years after that (2003), and so on.
- It should also take the percentage of those years (1993, 1998, 2003, 2008, 2013) and add them into a text. Like, 'You pay X%, Y%, Z%, etc.'
- To make things a little more complicated, for the input years 1992 (4,94%), 1993 (3,74%), 1994 (4,77%), 1996 (4,52%), 1997 (4,94%), 1998 (3,74%) and 1999 (4,77%), the percentages between () should be added on the date 3-1-2001.

  ```
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      exporting: {
      enabled: false
      },
      chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'spline',
          marginRight: 20
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Rente DUO'
      },
      subtitle: {
          text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
              month: '%Y',
              year: '%Y'
          }
      },
      yAxis: {
  min:0,
          title: {
              text: 'Werkloosheid (%)'
          },

                       plotLines: [{
              value: 0,
              width: 2,
              color: '#000000',
              zIndex: 5
          },            {
              label: {
      text: 'Rente DUO',
      align: 'right'
      },
      value: 5,
              width: 0.5,
              color: '#ffffff',
              zIndex: 1
          }]
      },
      tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
                  return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'<br/>'+
                  Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %Y', this.x) +':</b> '+ this.y +'%';
          }
      },

       plotOptions: {
      spline: {
          lineWidth: 3,
          states: {
              hover: {
                  lineWidth: 4
              }
          },
          marker: {
              enabled: false,
              states: {
                  hover: {
                      enabled: true,
                      symbol: 'circle',
                      radius: 4,
                      lineWidth: 1
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
             legend: {
  enabled: false
  },
  ```

​

If this is complicated, it could also be done by drawing a new graph after entering a year. This graph would be a step line graph with the same data.

How can this be made?

Comment: What time value should the chart start on? Do we load an empty chart or start on, for example, 1990?

Comment: Can you describe your 5th requirement better?

Comment: The chart should start at 1993. That's because before that date, there were other requirements for this system. I see that in 1993, the percentage should be 9,39. In the graph below, it displays null.

Comment: The fifth requirement:

- If you enter the year 1992, it should display the value 4,94% on the date 3-1-2001. This can be added in the text like 'From [date] you pay 4,94%'
- If you enter the year 1993, it should display 3,74% on th date 3-1-2001, etc.
- Only for these years: 1992 (4,94%), 1993 (3,74%), 1994 (4,77%), 1996 (4,52%), 1997 (4,94%), 1998 (3,74%) and 1999 (4,77%).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting requirements and I think I have all of them except for the fifth one.
To do this is fairly easy. You need [`plotLines`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines), input form, and another `<div>` element.

First you need to pull your year from the input form and add 1 year to it (not sure why +1 but here you go):

```
passedYear = parseInt($('input:text').val(), 10) + 1;
```

Then you need to convert this human readable year to a javascript time stamp:

```
showYear = Date.UTC(passedYear, 0, 1);
```

From here you also need to take into account if the user inputs a value higher than the max year of the data (and also less than the minimum). Here is how to test for the greater than scenario:

```
var extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
var maxYear;
maxYear = extremes.dataMax;
if (maxYear > showYear) {
     do stuff
}
```

You then create your initial `plotLine`:

```
    chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
        value: showYear,
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        id: 'plotLine'
    });
```

Next you wanted to show additional `plotLine` items at 5-year increments:

```
var plInterval;
plInterval = 5;
    while (nextPL < maxYear) {
        chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
            value: nextPL,
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            id: 'plotLine'
        });
        nextYear = nextYear + plInterval;
        nextPL = Date.UTC(nextYear, 0, 1);
    }
```

This is to assure that we do not add unnecessary `plotLine` items out to infinity that will never be shown.

Additional requirement was to show "You pay xxxx" text on the page. For this you need a `<div>` element (or whatever, up to you) to write to. To get the values there is a great function I pulled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014412/highcharts-getting-y-value-in-one-series-based-on-x-value-from-another-series):

```
function getYValue(chartObj, seriesIndex, xValue) {
    var yValue = null;
    var points = chartObj.series[seriesIndex].points;
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        if (points[i].x >= xValue) break;
        yValue = points[i].y;
    }
    return yValue;
}
```

I use it like:

```
var yVal1;
yVal1 = getYValue(chart, 0, maxYear);
strInterestPay = strInterestPay + yVal1 + '%, ';
```

I then write this `strInterestPay` to the `<div>`:

```
$("div:interest").html(strInterestPay);
```

Now, we need to write out the percentages for the additional `plotLine` items:

```
yVal1 = getYValue(chart, 0, nextPL);
strInterestPay = ', ' + yVal1 + '%';
$('.content').append(strInterestPay);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/aHja5/)

Comment: Whow, really interesting/usefull. Thank you. I've editted the chart to this: http://jsfiddle.net/jerryvermanen/mjvEK/1/. Still wondering about the fifth requirement. Could you help me out with that one? Look at the comments above.